# Примеры применения DI в Android

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, kodein

Решил немного изучить `Dependency Injection`, а именно библиотеку `Kodein` для `Kotlin`. Прочитал кучу статей, прочесал документацию но практического применения для себя так и не нашел. Само понятие - внедрение зависимостей, я вцелом понимаю. Обьясните где чаще всего данные либы используются в `Android`?(Буду благодарен за примеры кода).

Comment: Не помню на памяти, где не использовался DI в живых проектах. И вам точно надо уточнить вопрос где? вы имеете ввиду для чего в app? или где на рынке ?

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei, вот обычные примеры с проектов я и прошу(рынок меня не интересует), для меня это новая тема. В целом выплывает вопрос: А стоит ли это все делать? Простой проект превращается в что то ужасное и мало понятное.

Comment: @UjinUkr это всегда trade-off, нельзя однозначно сказать что всем проектам точно нужен di, любой шаблон нужно применять включая голову

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dependency Injection (DI) это шаблон проектирования.

Библиотеки реализующие DI это инструменты, которые могут помочь с организацией кода в целом и никак не относятся к тематике разрабатываемой программы или платформе, для которой пишется эта программа.

Обычно DI навязыввет свои правила написания кода, что немало усложняет простую программу, которая состоит из двух классов.

В небольшой программе DI выглядит громоздко и мягко говоря лишним, однако никак иначе новичку не объясняют, обычно учебный пример использования компактен, чтобы показать синтаксис не более.

За этим нужно разглядеть мотивацию, и так часто бывает, если Вы не видите для себя плюсов, значит скорее всего Вам и нет необходимости использовать DI.

В умелых руках DI позволяет уменьшить связность кода (в англоязычной литературе - code coupling).

Польза от DI появляется в настоящей, живой программе. Когда меняются требования и вам нужно "выпилить вон тот застарелый кусок джавна и заменить его на супер модную библиотеку которая все делает в 10 раз лучше".

Если в программе сильная связность между классами - такой рефакторинг это боль. Иной раз чтобы это понять нужно её испытать.

Обычно классы разработанные для внедрения легко тестируемы.

Но, как вы уже заметили этот подход не без минусов.

У DI фреймворков есть определенный порог вхождения, поэтому нужно потратить время и изучить его, прежде чем эффективно использовать.

DI усложняет отладку и анализ программы , т.к по коду уже так запросто не скажешь какая реализация появится в конкретный момент, нужно будет неплохо ориентироватться в программе, чтобы постоянно не запускать отладчик.